# How to use find_in_set in wp_query

Tags: wordpress

I have 2 meta key key1 and key2, i am looking for a query for using both key
here is my php query

```
$where = "keyone = 1 or FIND_IN_SET($id,  `keytwo` ) <>0";
```

its worked fine with the mysql however i am trying to convert this concept into wp_query but i am not getting any results.

[refrence guide from someone](https://gist.github.com/mikeschinkel/6402058#file-find-in-set-php)

this code also does not work

thanks in advance.

Comment: See [this similar post](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/18715/12496) about using a custom `LIKE` query. Basically you just need to filter the query's `WHERE` clause and inject your own SQL string.

Comment: this does not work for me i have to find in meta keys instead of title.

Answer (score 0):

The link I posted was just a way for you to inject your own custom `WHERE` clause which is probably your only option. If you look at the [source for `WP_Meta_Query`](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.4/src/wp-includes/class-wp-meta-query.php#L514) you'll see that the comparison operators are hard-coded. Because WordPress never really expected to store `SET` values there really isn't any native support for these, either. I would try something like this:

```
//Function to inject our custom WHERE clauses
function so_34594266_post_where( $where, &$wp_query )
{
    //Somehow this function needs to be made "aware" of the $id variable,
    //either a class-level variable, global (yuck) or some function call
    if( $wp_query->is_main_query() )
    {
        $where = "keyone = 1 or FIND_IN_SET($id,  `keytwo` ) <>0";
    }

    return $where;
}

//Tell WordPress to use our function
add_filter( 'post_where', 'so_34594266_post_where' );

//Get our posts (this could also be a WP_Query object or whatever else)
$posts = get_posts( '...your stuff here...' );

//Tell WordPress to stop using our function
remove_filter( 'post_where', 'so_34594266_post_where' );
```