# How to find users having a single meta value when meta key is an array?

Tags: php, wordpress

I'm trying to filter all users subscribed to a particular event.
All users have a meta field called '**signedto**', which stores event id the user is subscribed to.

Now, I'm trying to get only users subscribed to $event_id using a meta query, but it's not working as expected (**it's returning all users**).

This is the code I tried:

```
$event_ID = get_the_ID();
$args = array(
    'meta_query' => array(
        'key' => 'signedto',
        'value' => $event_ID, // I already tried with serialize($event_ID) and array($event_ID)
         'comparison' => 'IN' // not sure about it, I also tried with 'LIKE' 
    )
);
$users = get_users($args);
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: Neither IN or LIKE make much sense, when you want comparison with a single integer. That should just use the `=` operator.

Comment: Yes, actually I used them because I don't have a precise idea on how to solve this one.
$event_ID is a single integer as you said, but 'signedto' is an array of integers @misorude

Comment: Well then you can’t do “strict” comparison, of course. So in what form is that array actually stored in the database?

Comment: If I use `get_user_meta($user_id, 'signedto')`, I get `Array ( [0] => Array ( [1] => 1339 [2] => 1337 )`

Comment: That function has already converted the string read from the database for you, but that is not the original content stored there. Most likely it is PHP’s `serialize` format that gets stored into the DB - and that is not really suitable for “searching” in, for an array as you have shown, that would be `a:1:{i:0;a:2:{i:1;i:1339;i:2;i:1337;}}` You _can_ try and do a LIKE wildcard search in that, but that can easily give false positives, for example if you were to search for `LIKE %2%` here - that is not really one of the values, but part of the serialize “syntax”.

Comment: I understand...so there's no good way to filter users with a particular value in a field with multiple values, avoiding false positives?

Comment: If it really uses this format (I think, but better double check), then no, not really. This boils down to the age-old problem of proper normalization, and that multiple values should not be stored in one single record. Of course WP’s meta data system violates that rule a bit deliberately, to provide the necessary flexibility. You _could_ store your meta data as a string of comma-separated values instead - but then you would have to modify every place in the code where this is set or read accordingly, and handle the array-to-string conversion resp. vice versa yourself.

Comment: Then you could use FIND_IN_SET as described here, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34594266/how-to-use-find-in-set-in-wp-query, or if you add a comma before the first and after the last value as well, search using `LIKE %,123,%`